# Curved lines not covered dont seem to be covered by apps script: is that right?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I added a curved line in Gslides hoping I could adjust its appearance using apps script, but using the code below it seems as though they're not covered (log result say unsupported) - am I missing something.

`Logger.log(SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2b18c54f222_0_1').getPageElementType());`

Apoligies - I should have mentioned, the output from this line of code is "UNSUPPORTED", and the line was added using Insert>Line>Curve from the slides menu.

Comment: `I added a curved line` Please describe/demonstrate how this was done.

Comment: From the code, it's not very clear what you're doing. But they do have the Line class. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/line

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned the output from that line of code was "UNSUPPORTED". The page element referred to was added to the slide using insert / line / curve.

Comment: Following the comments from respondents I've switched to using a straight line. The colour of which can be changed in the code - but there seems to be a bug with changing the width. See question 77855679.